# Salesforce OAuth Access_Token null?

Tags: java, rest, oauth, salesforce

I am trying to implement the rest api sample given in the salesforce site link below.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API

I have set up project as said in the link, but when I am executing the project I am getting an error as "Error - no access token". When I do debug, I came to know that the variable accessToken is null.

> String accessToken = (String)
>   request.getSession().getAttribute("ACCESS_TOKEN");

I am bit confused about this problem.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: did you perform the initial authentication request to get the access token, and then did you store the token on the session?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are missing this part in your code:

```
// Set a session attribute so that other servlets can get the 
// access token
request.getSession().setAttribute(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken); 

// We also get the instance URL from the OAuth response, so set it
// in the session too
request.getSession().setAttribute(INSTANCE_URL, instanceUrl);
```